# Magento: How do I get category object (attached images, etc) from an arbitrary template?

Tags: templates, magento, categories

Basically I have custom template for the content on specific page and I would like to fetch all store categories, with accompained info (content, attached image, etc) and display it as a list of linked thumbs. So far I only managed to get the list of categories with:

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
```

But I need the other info as well, especially the attached image. How do I get it?

Comment: Please describe what you want to a bit more clearly! Your existing templates for browsing categories do what you describe, albeit not for every single product in your catalog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$cat_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection');

you should have everything

Comment: Can you tell me how you have found this? Is there a reference of these anywhere?

Comment: try this : http://freegento.com/ it might have reference to old versions but it is quite similar and helps alot.